# Not able to enter text in input box using selenium

Tags: html, input, selenium-webdriver

I have the following structure of the HTML.
I need to enter some text in the input field, but not able to enter it.

```
<body>
    <div style="z-index: 254; margin-left: -143px; top: 208.5px;" class="g">
        <div class="y">
        <div class="o">
          <div class="t">Add to Collections</div>
            <a class="l">
              <span class="po"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="a">
          <form>
            <div class="b">
              <input placeholder="Enter text here" name="qw" class="re" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="c">
              <a class="d">Add</a>
            </div>
            <ul id="e" class="f">
            </ul>
          </form>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean "not able to enter it"? What is happening?

Comment: i am getting no such element exception when i try to send text in the input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your script wait for an element to be loaded in the DOM. Use webdriver wait to achieve this. Look at below example.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("qw")));
```